# How do I get a Qt app running on MATE to open embedded URLs?

Tags: qt

I'm running Linux Mint with the MATE desktop. I'm using Everpad, which is a Python app that uses Qt.

When I click on an http URL in the text, nothing happens. I assume this is because Qt doesn't have the setting to find a handler for the link. How can I fix this so it opens it with Firefox?

Comment: What happens if you run `xdg-open http://www.googlw.com` from a terminal? Are URLs recognized by `everpad`? Are they highlighted or somehow give an indication that you can click on them?

Comment: xdg-open opens a new link in Chrome, even if Chrome is not running. In Everpad, the links are blue and underlined, and the cursor changes to a pointing-finger-hand when hovering over them. But clicking on them does nothing, even with both Firefox and Chrome running.